# Convert Zip File to byte[] and byte[] to zip file

Tags: c#, file

I try to convert zip file to byte[] and write it to a text file.

```
int BufferSize=65536;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult re = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (re == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"F:\Info.txt", bytes);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

Then I try to convert those byte to zip file. But I can't do it.

My code is here:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DialogResult re = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (re == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
            using (var mstrim = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                using (var inStream = new GZipStream(mstrim, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    using (var outStream = File.Create("Tax.Zip"))
                    {
                        var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                        int readBytes;
                        while ((readBytes = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, BufferSize)) != 0)
                        {
                            outStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

> Error:File Mode not valid.

What File Mode is needed and how can I accomplish what I described?

Comment: This indenting style really is not helpful. Press Ctrl-K,D.

Comment: Actually you have to decompress the zip file. reading the bytes from a zip file will not give you the actual data already compressed inside the file.
thats why you can't recreate the zip file from the bytes you have just read.

Comment: Use DotNetZIP: https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples

with that you can do much more work within less time and effort than Gzip. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try this.

```
            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\z.7z");
            File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\t.txt", data); // Requires System.IO

            byte[] newdata = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\t.txt");
            File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\a.7z", newdata); // Requires System.IO
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `GZipStream`, which is used for GZip files, not (PK-)Zip files. This isn't going to work, obviously. Try the `ZipFile` class instead (though sadly, it doesn't work on streams, just files).

Apart from simply being a different file format, the big difference is that GZip is for compression only, while Zip is also an archive (that is, it can contain multiple files).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         byte[] arr;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            arr = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\asik.zip");
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\\asik.txt", arr);
            ms.Close();
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\\asik.txt");
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            stream.Close();
            MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
            CreateToMemoryStream(ms1, @"D:\\asik.zip");
            ms1.Close();


    }

    public void CreateToMemoryStream(MemoryStream memStreamIn, string zipEntryName)
    {

        MemoryStream outputMemStream = new MemoryStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputMemStream);

        zipStream.SetLevel(3); //0-9, 9 being the highest level of compression

        ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(zipEntryName);
        newEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

        zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

        StreamUtils.Copy(memStreamIn, zipStream, new byte[4096]);
        zipStream.CloseEntry();

        zipStream.IsStreamOwner = false;    // False stops the Close also Closing the underlying stream.
        zipStream.Close();          // Must finish the ZipOutputStream before using outputMemStream.

        //outputMemStream.Position = 0;
        //return outputMemStream;

        //// Alternative outputs:
        //// ToArray is the cleaner and easiest to use correctly with the penalty of duplicating allocated memory.
        //byte[] byteArrayOut = outputMemStream.ToArray();

        //// GetBuffer returns a raw buffer raw and so you need to account for the true length yourself.
        //byte[] byteArrayOut2 = outputMemStream.GetBuffer();
        //long len = outputMemStream.Length;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BytesVal {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MoreZipException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("F:\\ssd\\doc\\");
        System.out.println("Byte inside the Zip file is" + BytesVal.getAllBytes(file));
    }

    public static byte[] getAllBytes(File folderName) throws IOException, MoreZipException {
        String[] sourceFiles = null;
        if (folderName.isDirectory()) {
            sourceFiles = folderName.list();
            if (sourceFiles.length > 1) {

                throw new MoreZipException(sourceFiles.length);

            }
        }
        byte[] bytes = null;

        Path filePath = Paths.get("F:/ssd/doc/" + sourceFiles[0]);
        bytes = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: create one Custom Exception class named as MoreZipException  by extending Exception class

Comment: Please edit the answer and add an explanation to the code you have provided.

Comment: inside doc folder there will be only one .zip file otherwise it will throw exception , if one .zip file it will give you the Byte[] of the file.