# Convert byte[] returned by a 3rd party software to zip file

Tags: asp.net

Was going through stackoverflow article [Convert to Zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034573/convert-zip-file-to-byte-and-byte-to-zip-file), but my issue is a bit different. I do not have the PDF file. I get the array of bytes array after HTML is converted to PDF via a 3rd party software called [HiQPDF](http://www.hiqpdf.com/) and I want to convert the same array to zip file. My code for converting the byte array to zip is

```
private void  DownloadZipFile(HttpContext aHttpContext, byte[] pdfBuffer)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    archive.CreateEntry(NomineeName + ".pdf", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                }

                //return the ZIP byte stream as base 64 string
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                byte[] zipArchive = memoryStream.ToArray();

                aHttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

                aHttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename={1}; size={2}",
                                                  "attachment", "\"" + this.NomineeName + ".zip\"", zipArchive.Length));

                aHttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

                aHttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(zipArchive);

                aHttpContext.Response.End();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            new LogDetails { Exception = exception }.AddLog();

            this.ShowErrorMessage(aHttpContext);
        }

    }
```

This codes downloads the zip file but I know I am missing something somewhere as a result of which I cannot open the pdf after extracting it.

> pdfBuffer in the parameter is the byte array returned by the HiQPDF.

Thanks for the help. I know I am duplicating the question but I need to know where I am wrong. I searched plenty of articles and blogs but still I couldn't find where my mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

With a little R&D I found out that I was not writing the data into the newly created entry in zip file thus I missed couple of lines of code:

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
 {
    writer.Write(pdfBuffer);
 }
```

Adding these lines of code after

```
archive.CreateEntry(NomineeName + ".pdf", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
```

fixed my problem.